# Git, tortoisegit. How to run my cmd file after every commit

Tags: git, gitlab, git-commit, tortoisegit

I use tortoisegit. How can I run my cmd file after commit on some of my repositories . I mean use an event on commit on repository?. I do all of my meaningful commits only by tortoisegit and i need it only for such commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git has post-commit hooks, which are scripts or commands that are called automatically after a commit has successfully completed. It looks like TortoiseGit supports those too, at least according to the documentation: https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-hooks

Comment: Thanks. It works. I have tested post commit